# React - how to change state within component from another component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, state

heres what I'm trying to do; I have a several components within App.js, including the navigation bar.

Currently, I have some code within App.js which hides several of the components in App.js onClick of a button, and displays a different view at the same time.

What I am trying to do is move the Button to the navigation bar, but still be able to switch the view in App.js. How should I share the state between navigationbar and App.js.

Here is my App.js code;

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTerm: "",
      fileType: "",
      resultStats: {},
      sidebarShowing: false,
      resultFile: {},
      showMainView: false,
      featuresVisible: true,
    };
    this.searchReturn = this.searchReturn.bind(this);
    this.fileTypeChanged = this.fileTypeChanged.bind(this);
    this.resultStatsParse = this.resultStatsParse.bind(this);
    this.fileClicked = this.fileClicked.bind(this);
    this.onHide = this.onHide.bind(this);
    this.settingsFound = this.settingsFound.bind(this);
    this.togglemainView = this.toggleMainView.bind(this);
  }

  toggleMainView = () =>
    this.setState({
      showMainView: !this.state.showMainView,
      featuresVisible: !this.state.featuresVisible,
   });

  settingsFound(style) {
    console.log("Found style");
    console.log(style);
    this.setState({ style: style });
  }

  searchReturn(searchResult) {
   console.log(searchResult);
   this.setState({ searchTerm: searchResult });
  }

  fileTypeChanged(fileType) {
   console.log(fileType);
   this.setState({ fileType });
 }

 resultStatsParse(resultStats) {
   console.log(resultStats);
   this.setState({ resultStats: resultStats });
 }

 fileClicked(file) {
   this.setState({ resultFile: file });
   this.setState({ sidebarShowing: true });
   console.log(file);
}

 onHide() {
   this.setState({ sidebarShowing: false });
}

render() {
const { showMainView } = this.state;

let showingResultsText = (
  <>
    Found {this.state.resultStats.totalResults} Results out of{" "}
    {this.state.resultStats.totalDocuments} for{" "}
    <span>{this.state.searchTerm}</span> in{" "}
    {this.state.resultStats.timeTook}ms
  </>
);
let fileText = <></>;
if (!this.state.searchTerm)
  showingResultsText = (
    <>
      Found {this.state.resultStats.totalResults} Results out of{" "}
      {this.state.resultStats.totalDocuments} in{" "}
      {this.state.resultStats.timeTook}ms
    </>
  );

if (this.state.fileType !== "") {
  fileText = (
    <>
      {" "}
      showing only <span>.{this.state.fileType}</span>
    </>
  );
}

let sidebarActive = this.state.sidebarShowing;
let style = this.state.style;

if (style == undefined) {
  return (
    <>
      <SettingsFetchComponent
        styleUpdated={this.settingsFound}
      ></SettingsFetchComponent>
      Loading your settings, please wait...{" "}
    </>
  );
}

return (
  <>
    <NavBar
      onSearchTermChanged={this.searchReturn}
      styleOptions={this.state.style}
      showMainView={this.state.showMainView}
      featuresVisible={this.state.featuresVisible}
    ></NavBar>

    <div>
      {this.state.featuresVisible ? (
        <div
          className="content"
          style={{ backgroundColor: style.backgroundColor }}
        >
          <div
            className="sidebar"
            style={{ backgroundColor: style.sidebarBackgroundColor }}
          >
            <FileTypeBar
              fileTypeChanged={this.fileTypeChanged}
              styleOptions={this.state.style}
            ></FileTypeBar>
          </div>
          <div
            className="results"
            style={{ backgroundColor: style.backgroundColor }}
          >
            <div
              className="resultsSubheader"
              style={{ color: style.secondaryTextColor }}
            >
              {showingResultsText}
              {fileText}
            </div>
            <SearchResultList
              onFileActiveChange={this.fileClicked}
              searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm}
              fileType={this.state.fileType}
              pageNumber={1}
              onResultsStats={this.resultStatsParse}
              styleOptions={this.state.style}
            ></SearchResultList>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>

    <div>
      <button onClick={this.toggleMainView}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </>
);
}
}
```

And here is my NavigationBar code;

```
export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }

render() {
 let style = this.props.styleOptions;
 return (
   <nav
    class="navbar fixed-top"
    style={{
      backgroundColor: style.navBackground,
      borderColor: style.navBorderColor,
    }}
  >
    <div
      className="nav-brand-conainter"
      style={{ backgroundColor: style.navLogoBackground }}
    >
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src={style.logoUrl} alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div className="navbar-contents">
      <SearchBar
        onSearchTermChanged={this.props.onSearchTermChanged}
        style={{ color: style.secondaryTextColor }}
      ></SearchBar>
    </div>
    <UserBox></UserBox>
  </nav>
);
}
}
```

I would like to be able to hide the components in App.js from NavBar Button, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code it seems that you already know how to do. Just take `onSearchTermChanged`as an example.

In your `NavigationBar` component do so :

```
    ...
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.props.onToggle}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
    ...
```

If your nav bar needs to know the state you might consider adding an extra handler:

```
  constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggle() {
    this.setState({ toggled: !this.state.toggled });
    this.props.onToggle();
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleToggle}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
    ...
  }
```

And in your App component :

```
    ...
    <NavBar
      onSearchTermChanged={this.searchReturn}
      onToggle={this.toggleMainView} // <----
      styleOptions={this.state.style}
      showMainView={this.state.showMainView}
      featuresVisible={this.state.featuresVisible}
    ></NavBar>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To share the state in one component you can use the HOC or higher order component to do that. Please follow the video link below to get the HOC clearly. I think this will help to fix your issue
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6aNv8nkUSw